# Nested FXML and bidirectional data binding example

Tags: javafx, data-binding, nested, fxml, bidirectional

two days ago I asked for help regarding nested FXML using bidirectional binding of text properties (see [Cannot receive user entered data from nested FXML using bindbidirectional binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40270248/cannot-receive-user-entered-data-from-nested-fxml-using-bindbidirectional-bindin)). Unfortunatly I didn't receive any feedback on this particular problem. Therefore I thought I raise the question in a broader way: Can anybody provide a working example of nested FXML, where the inner controller uses bidirectional binding, ideally to a text property, between the data model and FXML UI controls?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not exactly the same as your setup (though it's fairly trivial to refactor it so the main view is a single FXML with includes for the other FXML files), but https://github.com/james-d/SimpleMVP works just fine. The editor controller bonds bidirectionally based on a value that is set.

Comment: "bonds"'should of course be "binds".

Comment: I fixed it building upon this example: http://blog.buildpath.de/fxml-composition-how-to-get-the-controller-of-an-included-fxml-view-nested-controllers/. Thanks to Sialcasa